# How to get the widget's current x and y coordinates?

Tags: python, tkinter, move

I'm currently writing a game project as for the game "4 in a row". To make the animation where the picture widget disk falls in the column, I've been thinking about creating a while loop for as in:

```
while widgetx != __ and widgety != __
```

where at the blank parts there will be the values I'll need to get.

My question is if there's a function that returns the current `x` and `y` value for a widget.

Comment: Are you asking about the position of a widget (Button, Frame, Label, etc), or of an object drawn on a canvas?

Answer (score 18):

[winfo_rootx()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_rootx-method) and [winfo_rooty()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_rooty-method) return the coordinates relative to the screen's upper left corner. [winfo_x](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_x-method) and [winfo_y](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_y-method) return the coordinates of a window relative to its parent.

Comment: Don't forget that sometimes you have to use `root.update()` before being able to use winfo_x and winfo_y. (Else you will only have 1 and 0 as values)

Answer (score 8):

You can try [winfo_rootx()](http://nullege.com/codes/search/Tkinter.Button.winfo_rooty) and [winfo_rooty()](http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=Tkinter.Button.winfo_rootx).

From [effbot.com](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm):

> ### [winfo_rootx()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_rootx-method)
>
> > Get the pixel coordinate for the widget’s left edge, relative to the screen’s upper left corner.
> >
> > Returns: The root coordinate.
>
> ### [winfo_rooty()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_rooty-method)
>
> > Get the pixel coordinates for the widget’s upper edge, relative to the screen’s upper left corner.
> >
> > Returns: The root coordinate.

An example from [nullege.com](http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=Tkinter.Button.winfo_rootx):

```
# get self position & height
lv_x = self.winfo_rootx()
lv_y = self.winfo_rooty()
```