# How to print the items in a tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code:

```py
root= tk.Tk()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Button', command=lambda:print("Click"))
button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

Label = tk.Label(root, text="Text")
Label.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

What I want to get:

```
Button:(1, 1), Label:(1, 2)
```

How can I print the items and their destinations in root?

Comment: destinations?What's that?

Comment: Well, I want to find where `button1` and `Label` is located.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the widget's current x and y coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257574/how-to-get-the-widgets-current-x-and-y-coordinates)

Comment: Not really ....

Comment: What do you hope to do with this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the information about `grid`, use `grid_info()` could get the info about the widget.To get all the widgets on `root`, just use `root.winfo_children()`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Button', command=lambda:print("Click"))
button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

Label = tk.Label(root, text="Text")
Label.grid(row=1, column=2)

for widget in root.winfo_children():
    print(f"{widget.widgetName}:({ widget.grid_info()['row']}, {widget.grid_info()['column']})")

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
button:(1, 1)
label:(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this solve it? What you do is create a function that generates a label in root and then give it to the command argument of your button.

```
import tkinter as tk
root= tk.Tk()

def x():
  y = tk.Label(root, text = "Click")
  y.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Button', command=x)

button1.grid(row=1, column=1)

Label = tk.Label(root, text="Text")
Label.grid(row = 2, column = 1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, It is not that i want to print the text in `root`,  it is that I want to find where `button1` and `Label` is located.

Comment: oh, please try to make that more clearer. you can make their grid coordinates variables and then return them in the function @JohnIson

Comment: Well, what I want is like as if I created all of them, And I want to find out where they are with just some extra commands.